# Selenium Webdriver Python I am selecting all checkboxes from html table I get the error Element is no longer valid

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a table with 4 rows.  There is a checkbox in the first column for each row.  4 checkboxes as there are 4 rows.  A checkbox for Name, Address, DOB, Phone

I want to select all of the checkboxes.  My code does this as I can see the checkboxes being ticked when i run my Selenium Python code.
When all checkboxes are ticked it throws the error:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer valid
```

My code method implentation is as follows:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

def click_all_variables_from_variables_section(self):
    #checkboxes = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_vars_usn input[type='checkbox']")
    #checkboxes = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "'#reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_vars_usn input[type='checkbox']'")))
    checkboxes = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_vars_usn"]//input[@type="checkbox"]')
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        checkbox.click()
    return self
```

From my code you can see some comments of what else I have tried e.g. WebDriverWait.  When i tried WebDriverWait it stayed stuck in a loop for a very long time.  I had to close to the browser to exit.

The HTML is:

```
 <table id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_vars_usn" class="GLKP2TGBJE" cellspacing="0" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingfocus="true" __gwtcellbasedwidgetimpldispatchingblur="true">
    <thead aria-hidden="false">
        <colgroup>
            <tbody style="">
                <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD GLKP2TGBJD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="0">
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBED GLKP2TGBKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-488" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-489" style="outline-style:none;">Name</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-490" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <select tabindex="-1">
                                <option selected="selected" value="0">0</option>
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-491" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <select tabindex="-1">
                                <option selected="selected" value="" />
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBOD GLKP2TGBKD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-492" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="text" tabindex="-1" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GLKP2TGBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="1">
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-488" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-489" style="outline-style:none;">Address</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-490" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <select tabindex="-1">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-491" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <select tabindex="-1">
                                <option selected="selected" value="" />
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-492" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="text" tabindex="-1" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GLKP2TGBCD" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="2">
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-488" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-489" style="outline-style:none;">DOB</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-490" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <select tabindex="-1">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-491" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <select tabindex="-1">
                                <option selected="selected" value="" />
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDD GLKP2TGBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-492" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="text" tabindex="-1" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="GLKP2TGBCE" __gwt_subrow="0" __gwt_row="3">
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBED">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-488" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="-1" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-489" style="outline-style:none;">Phone</div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-490" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <select tabindex="-1">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-491" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <select tabindex="-1">
                                <option selected="selected" value="" />
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <td class="GLKP2TGBBD GLKP2TGBDE GLKP2TGBOD">
                        <div __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-492" style="outline-style:none;">
                            <input type="text" tabindex="-1" value="" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody style="display: none;">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" colspan="5">
                        <div>
                            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="gwt-Label">No data to display.</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;" aria-hidden="false">
                                <div class="GLKP2TGBBE" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" aria-hidden="false">
                                    <div class="gwt-Label">Loading...</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot style="" aria-hidden="false">
</table>
```

The full error trace is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\TestCases\ReportingPage_TestCase.py", line 53, in test_add_matches_report
    reports_page.click_all_variables_from_variables_section()
  File "C:\Webdriver\ClearCore\Pages\reports.py", line 75, in click_all_variables_from_variables_section
    checkbox.click()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 65, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 402, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 175, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element is no longer valid
```

I have also tried waiting for the table to load first then click the checkboxes.
My code is:

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, '//table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_vars_usn"]')))
    checkboxes = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="reporting_add_report_tab_manual_ct_vars_usn"]//input[@type="checkbox"]')
    for checkbox in checkboxes:
        checkbox.click()
```

This one throws a TimeoutException

How can i solve this, click all of the checkboxes without there being any errors?

Thanks,
Riaz

Comment: I would try writing the outerHTML of `checkbox` before clicking it then see which one is causing the issue. My guess is that clicking the checkboxes is modifying the HTML of the page that is causing the issue.

Comment: how many times does your for loop run ? It might be possible that there is extra checkboxes detected by Selenium